# How do I avoid except returning an empty object class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, exception

I want to include an except inside a class, but when I run the code, the except is returning an empty class object. How can I make the except return only the error message and nothing else?

```
class InputError(Exception):
    """Raised when input format not allowed"""
    pass

class ReadMap1:
    def __init__(self, input):
        try:
            if (type(input) == str) | (type(input) == int):
                if type(input) == str:
                    self.input = input
                else:
                    self.input = str(input)
            else:
                raise InputError
        except InputError:
            print("----Input not allowed----")
```

Output:

```
ReadMap1([1])
----Input not allowed----
<__main__.ReadMap1 object at 0x0000024B30B49FD0>
```

Comment: Yh makes sense. The attributes are being set only inside the `try` block and not the `except` block. That's why it returns an empty object.

Comment: Don't catch that error in the `__init__` -- catch it _outside_ from wherever you call `ReadMap1()`, and handle that error there. Also note that `__init__` doesn't return anything, it only _initializes_ the object

Comment: The code is already only returning the error message and nothing else. You are using Jupyter to write this?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7. Is there a way to avoid the initialization if a certain condition is not satisfied?

Answer (score 0):

Many people confuse Python's `__init__` with *constructors* from other languages, because like a constructor, `__init__` is often used to initialize attributes. However, `__init__` is **not** a constructor, but an *initializer*. The distinction is subtle though not terribly complicated in practice: The constructor *constructs* and returns an object, hence you can do `my_obj = ClassConstructor()` whereas the initializer only works on the object that the constructor already created. This is why Python's `MyClass.__init__` returns nothing.

Your code is behaving as expected. You have told it:

```
if input is a string or integer, then do some stuff
if input is another type, then crash with InputError
if the above ever crashes with InputError, print an error message instead of crashing and move on
```

Then you pass the initializer `[1]` which is a Python `list`. This being neither a string nor a number, the interpreter raises an `InputError`. Normally exceptions cause a crash, but since you have the try catch, the crash is then negated, and instead a message is printed.

You can "fix" this trivially by changing your `except` clause to be like:

```
except InputError:
    print("----Input not allowed----")
    self.input = "default value"
```

It sounds like you want the initialization to be aborted in this case. Then you should remove the `try-except`, and let `__init__` crash. The caller will then have to create the object like so:

```
try:
   rm = ReadMap1([1])
except InputError:
   print("----Input not allowed----")
```

Or you could omit the `try-except` here as well and allow the entire program to crash. It all depends: If `input` was invalid, could you program a way for your program to keep ticking, or is everything lost regardless?

---

There some additional issues in your code:

- `input` is the name of a [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) -- it's better to avoid shadowing it. Find a more unique name for your argument.
- If you are going to check types in your `if`, you don't need `try`. You would either `try` to use the value and handle `except TypeError`, or you would use `if type(...`, not both.
- It makes little sense to `raise` an exception inside a `try` that catches it. `try` is useful when the exception may arise form somewhere deep inside the code you are calling, and it would be impractical to directly check for the problem. In this case it is evident that you can check the type yourself, instead of relying on exceptions, so just do that.
- If you are merely converting the value to a string, you don't need to check the type at all. Just do `self.input = str(input)`. If it's already a string, Python will pass it unaltered. Everything else will be converted to a string (by calling the object's [or its parents'] `.__str__` method).

Comment: It was really illustrative your explanation. The code I posted is in fact a simplification of the main code, and this class is used in other methods and classes, that's the reason why I need to let the user know whether the input is allowable or not. My initial solution was using sys.exit, but it closes python and I just need to stop running the code without closing python

Comment: @DavidMontoyaGonzález Well, it seems reasonable to let the program crash (you can just let Exception be uncaught instead of `sys.exit`) in this situation. But if you don't want that, I think a more conventional approach would be `except InputError: rm = None`. So rather than creating an "empty" object, create a null object. This would be done by the caller, not your class, but if you really want to you can override `__new__` as in Mark's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* define [`__new__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) in order to intercept the creation of the object. You can return `None` here given a certain condition. Doing that will prevent `__init__()` from being called.

```
class ReadMap:
    def __new__(cls, input):
        if (type(input) == str) | (type(input) == int):
            return super().__new__(cls)
        
        print("----Input not allowed----")
        return None
    
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input

o = ReadMap(1)
o.input
# 1

p = ReadMap([1])
# prints ----Input not allowed----
print(p)
# None
```

I suspect this isn't a great idea, but I don't know how you are using this. It's pretty unexpected for the caller to call `ReadMap()` and get `None`, but it *is* possible. In general, I would opt for raising and letting the caller deal with the bad input — they after all sent the bad input.